# ¿Repetir una sentencia sql con un while en php?

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

Explico mi situación, tengo un código donde un administrador elige una cantidad de "locales" y los asocia a un nombre, una vez, hecho esto, se modifica la base de datos para asignar "locales" disponibles al nombre que da el administrador y se crean 2 eventos por cada local tomado. Hago esto, con un ciclo while, pero, el query para agregar 2 eventos no sirve, es decir, solo se ejecuta una única vez:

```php
$query = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM QR_CODES WHERE id_proyecto ='$pr_id'");
    while ($valores = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $id_qr = $valores[id];
        $query = $mysqli -> query("INSERT INTO INFORMACION_EVENTOS (id,titulo, informacion,lugar,id_qr, posicion, id_proyecto) VALUES (NULL,'no_name','no_text','$nombre','$id_qr', 1, '$pr_id'), (NULL,'no_name','no_text','$nombre','$id_qr', 2, '$pr_id')");
    }
```

La idea es que, se seleccionan los "locales" (en qr_codes) asociados al proyecto, y de ahí, por cada selección, se toma el id, y con este y otras variables se hacen 2 inserts, y esto se repite una y otra vez. Pero la sentencia sql solo se repite una vez (y se que el ciclo while sirve porque me muestra todas las id de "qr_codes" tomadas y no unas cuantas)

¿Que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Saludos. ¿Ya revisaste que tu `WHERE` al buscar `id_proyecto` te devuelva más de un solo registro?; así mismo revisa `$id_qr = $valores[id];` esta correcto así o debe ser algo como `$id_qr = $valores["id"];`.

Comment: si, devuelve más de una id,y son los correctos

Comment: Una primera cosa que no haces es comprobar que cada query es correcta. Puedes poner la query dentro de un try/catch y comprobar excepciones. La otra es que no compones una única sql con todos los values antes de ejecutar tu query de inserción. Eso te hace muchas consultas cuando lo puedes resolver en una.

Comment: Y si en lugar de en una sola sentencia expuesta a inyección de SQL creas un statement con PDO y lo llamas 2 veces para hacer inserciones más seguras? También mejora un poco el performance, por cierto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Se me ocurre que en lugar de un `while` uses un `foreach` la idea es basicamente la misma, quedando de la siguiente manera

```
    $query = $mysqli -> query("SELECT * FROM QR_CODES WHERE id_proyecto ='$pr_id'");
    foreach(mysqli_fetch_array($query) AS $v) {
       
       $id_qr = $v["id"];
       /*SETAS TODAS TUS VARIABLES E INSERTAS REGISTRO POR REGISTRO*/
    }
```

Comment: Cuidado con la inyección SQL...

Comment: Sin duda la mejor práctica es usar queries preparadas sin embargo esa es la forma más rápido de lograr su cometido sin envolverlo en la parte teórica y práctica, además de que el mejor modo sería con DAO y POO.

Comment: donde veis un problema de sql injection en esta consulta? lo digo porque el usuario no muestra el tratamiento de sus parametros en ningun momento...

Comment: En la parte que yo puse hay una posible filtracion de seguridad en la variable que se pasa de forma explicita sobre la consulta `WHERE id_proyecto ='$pr_id'` donde segun las buenas practicas deberia ser declara de la siguiente manera `WHERE id_proyecto =?` para poner con queries preparadas el valor y evitar inyecciones SQL, por eso reafirmo que la mejor manera es usando queries preparadas, objetos DAO y POO

Comment: De hecho hice eso hace 2 días y me sirvió (se me olvido auto-responder mi pregunta)

muchas gracias!

Comment: A pesar que la respuesta cumple, yo te recomendaría mirar ````trigger```` y ````stored procedure```` para una solución más eficiente.

Comment: El problema de los procedimientos en mysql es que si no los optimizas de forma correcta acabas consumiendo mas recursos de los necesarios, ademas de que debes tener mas experiencia, si esta empezando lo mejor es usar queries preparadas, solo en casos especializados usar  `trigger` y `stored procedure` a no ser que tengas la experiencia para hacerlo, incluso puedes usar `views` y `functions` para cosas mas complejas o usar `cron jobs`